# Regex to match everything but limit certain characters

Tags: regex

I have php code that asks for a search-term, splits it, and generates a regex to match (and highlight) the pattern. For example:
If I enter `ou`, it generates following pattern: `(o)(.*)(u)`. It then replaces it with `<em>$1</em>$2<em>$3</em>`.
In following data

```
boau #fie diu1^^j dauijz16 abc123 wwx,usq
```

this would have the following effect:

```
b<strong>o</strong>au #fie diu1^^j dauijz16 abc123 wwx,<strong>u</strong>sq
```

The problem is that I would like to be able to limit for example the number of spaces allowed in the match. For example, if I limit spaces to 3, that would have following result:

```
b<strong>o</strong>au #fie diu1^^j da<strong>u</strong>ijz16 abc123 wwx,usq
```

Or a limit of 3 spaces an max 1 `^`:

```
b<strong>o</strong>au #fie di<strong>u</strong>1^^j dauijz16 abc123 wwx,usq
```

Or, don't allow any digits:

```
b<strong>o</strong>au #fie di<strong>u</strong>1^j dauijz16 abc123 wwx,usq
```

So I would like to be able to enter the pattern to search for, and specify a separate limit for certain characters, I have no idea on how to do this though. I think it'll have something to do with a lookahead, but I can't figure out how to use those.

Answer (score 1):

To limit the number of spaces, I'd use:

```
(o)((?:\S*\s){0,3}\S*)(u)
```

Here is a perl script that uses it:

```
my $re = qr/(o)((?:\S*\s){0,3}\S*)(u)/;
my $str = 'boau #fie d iu1^^j dauij z16 abc123 wwx,usq';
$str =~ s!$re!<em>$1</em>$2<em>$3</em>!;
say $str;
```

**output:**

```
b<em>o</em>au #fie d i<em>u</em>1^^j dauij z16 abc123 wwx,usq
```

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:(o)((?:\S*\s){0,3}.*?)(u))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    o                        'o'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (between 0 and
                             3 times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \S*                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t,
                               \f, and " ") (0 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){0,3}                   end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S*                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (0 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    u                        'u'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: the `.*?` also matches a space, so the entire regex actually matches 4 spaces inbetween, instead of 3. Also, how would I go about adding limits for other characters? I've tried a few things, but they don't work..

Comment: @DaJF: Just replace the `.*?` with `\S*`. See my edit.

Comment: Ok, but what about the other requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You have asked quite a few questions here.

I am going to answer the one that appears most complex i.e. **if I limit spaces to 3**:

You can use this regex:

```
$s = 'boau #fie diu1^^j dauijz16 abc123 wwx,usq';
$r = preg_replace('/(o)((?:[^ ]* ){0,3}[^ u]*)(u)/', "<em>$1</em>$2<em>$3</em>", $s);
//=> b<em>o</em>au #fie diu1^^j da<em>u</em>ijz16 abc123 wwx,usq
```

**Explanation:**

```
1st Capturing group (o)
o matches the character o literally (case sensitive)
2nd Capturing group ((?:[^ ]* ){0,3}[^ u]*)
(?:[^ ]* ){0,3} Non-capturing group
Quantifier: Between 0 to 3 times
[^ ]* match a single character not present in the list below
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back
as needed [greedy]
  the literal character  
  matches the character   literally
[^ u]* match a single character not present in the list below
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back
as needed [greedy]
 u a single character in the list  u literally (case sensitive)
3rd Capturing group (u)
u matches the character u literally (case sensitive)
```

**This output matches with your expected result. I hope you can use the same approach and build regex for other parts of your questions with this.**

Comment: Agreed, and for that case `{0,3}` should be used as you have also shown.

Comment: I've changed your regex a bit to `(o)((?:[^ ]*\s[^ ]*){0,3}[^ ]*)(u)`, and this works perfectly for the _limit-spaces_ requirement. I've tried a few things to add limitations for other characters, but all of 'em don't work. Seems like I don't understand enough about regex.. Could you help me out on how to sequentially add further requirements?

Comment: Sure I can help. Just let me know for which requirement of yours you need my help?

Comment: say I want to have following limitations: [max 2 **spaces**; between 3 and 8 **#** signs; max 1 \ ]  
 I need to be able to generate this with php. I'm not asking for php code, but a regex that can be built sequentially.

Comment: That requires lookahead. So for your query you can use: `(?=(\S*\s){0,2}\S*$)(?=([^#]*#){3,8}[^#]*$)(?=[^\]]*\][^\]]*$)`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of negated classes:

```
(o)((?:[^ ]* ){0,3}[^ ]*)(u)
```

For limiting at 3 spaces.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/dE6aV2)

```
(o)(\D*)(u)
```

For no digits. `\D` matches any character except digits. Note that it is equivalent to the negated class: `[^\d]`.

The second requirement is much more complex than the above two:

```
(o)([^ ^]*(?:(\^)|( ))?[^ ^]*(?(3) |(?:( )|(\^)))?[^ ^]*(?(6) |(?:( )|(\^)))?[^ ^]*(?(8) |\^)?[^ ^]*)(u)
```

It tries to match either a `^` or a space and depending on what it captures, it will decide whether it can match another space or caret or none.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/oS6fT6)

**This regex makes use of conditional groups, which is not supported by all regex engines.**

As you can see, one limitation is quite easy, but multiple will be getting out of hand quickly. I would suggest a state machine if you have multiple conditions, for example, in pseudo code:

```
match first character "o"
substring = "o"

statecaret = 0
statespace = 0

for (check next character)
    if character == "^"
        statecaret = statecaret + 1
    else if character == " "
        statespace = statespace + 1

    if (statecaret = 2 || statespace = 4)
        break and reject character
    else
        add character to substring

find last "u" in substring
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use several regex one after the other to extract piece of the string by piece and last do a replace. But I still think you'd be better off without regex.